Closure votes for "lack of context": maybe voter has to understand the question first?
I've noticed several times in the past that good questions — well, good from the viewpoint of a mathematician, as in "having an interesting answer, quite difficult to derive from a surface-level literature search, and generally appealing either as a brain teaser or an illuminating example" — were closed as "lacking context."
Here's a recent example: What is the profinite completion of the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[X]$?
Is the real problem here that
a) the question "lacks context," or possibly,
b) the users who decided to close the question lack context?
The lack of context is likely preventing those users from realizing that the question is actually very natural to ask and would be useful for anyone beginning to learn the basics of some relatively obscure subject — as profinite rings — by searching on the web (as I usually do).
I'm not sure what could be a reasonable way to quell the urges of the context police.
So, I propose an improvement for current review process.

Add a recommendation (somewhere in the review queue) to NOT close any
question that is
a) written in clear English;
b) does not have formatting issues; and
c) is well out of the scope of a person deciding whether to close
it.

P.S. To add context to my question I can elaborate a bit. Current consensus of some vocal moderators (as far as I can tell) is more or less based on the premise that average author of a question is acting in bad faith (or, at least, has a tendency to do that), while a person pressing buttons in closure queue is acting in good faith. My experience seems to be differing regarding reviewers (again, as fas as I can tell from the results I see). Therefore, the question: is such excercise of power as closure of a question justified in case where the main problem is the reviewer, who fails to discern questions which have intrinsic value regardless of context?
P.P.S. After a quick unanimous decision to close this question as duplicate, I take my time to REITERATE my proposal.
I'm not just raising the question "What should we do with a so-called «problem-statement questions»?". Instead, I'm proposing a feature — either adding a line to the community policy (which would be a very easy task, if agreed upon), or a reminder in review interface (which probably requires more effort, but can be easily postponed until a community policy change takes place).
Content of this addition is: exerting caution with deciding whether a question lacks context if a reviewer does not understand the question because of lack of knowledge on the subject, despite question being written clearly, albeit briefly. This is a reminder that both difficulty in understanding, and appearance of lacking context do not necessarily stem from poor wording or insufficient verbiage, but very well may be caused by reviewer's lack of knowledge.
P.P.P.S. I'm not saying that very brief questions are good. I admit (and wholeheartedly agree) that they could be improved by adding refences for further reading, specifying the level of sophistication that's expected from an answer, pointing caveats in naive attempts to solve it et cetera. I'm posing an opinion that any mathematically nontrivial and nontrivially answerable question — and this combination of qualities takes effort to recognise! — without provided context is much more valuable asset for the humanity and MSE userbase than vast majority (I'm tempted to say "any", but I will abstain) of mathematically trivial or almost trivial questions, regardless of quality of exposition.

For those arguing that this should be reopened:  the issue raised here appears to be basically the same issue (i.e. should people who don't know a topic well be permitted to vote on questions pertaining to that topic).  This post is really the same question, along with a proposed answer.  The answer portion of this post could easily be posted as an answer to the linked question, making this version redundant.

To those who want to close this question (again) as a duplicate: Realize that you are creating a catch-22. How is someone supposed to make a new proposal on an old topic which already had a different proposal?

@NickAlger Again, the question points out a problem, answers can suggest solutions to that problem.  The question part of this post is a duplicate; the proposal can (and should) be posted as an answer to the linked duplicate.
